# Is there a way to keep the loaded excel files and variables in the memory to save up time?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm working on lots of data using tens of huge csv files. the whole code runs and csv files load into variables everytime the program compiles. is there a way to keep those loaded data in the memory and their assigned variables and just run and compile the changes i make add the bottom of the code?

Comment: have you tried using [jupyter](https://jupyter.org/)

Comment: No i use Visual studio code

Comment: i was recommending you to use `jupyter` all objects are kept in memory as you work

Comment: Let me know if that's all you need and I will post as an answer

Comment: Yeah, i'm looking into how to install it now. the description seems to be my solution to this agony i've been having.

Comment: Skip the install for learning and testing. Use `launch binder` button under listing of “Python environment with requirements.txt” [here](https://mybinder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sample_repos.html#python-environment-with-requirements-txt) to run with pandas already installed. You can change the end of the URL as described [here](https://github.com/binder-examples/jupyterlab#create-a-binder-link-that-points-to-jupyterlab) to switch to the JupyterLab interface and use drag and drop into the file navigation pane on left to upload your files from you local machine. Download useful results.

Comment: if that's all you need please don't forget to [accept_the_answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try `jupyter notebooks` it keeps all objects in memory while you work

Download [here](https://jupyter.org/)